# What files need to be deployed with a VS2019 app with a report viewer control

Tags: vb.net

I have a VS 2019 app that uses a report viewer control. The control was added to the ToolBox by adding the file "[ProjectName]\packages\Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.150.1484.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll. There are a bunch of other files in this \package folder.

Which of these folders and/or files need to be deployed with this app. I'm using InnoSetup to create the deployment package? Should I deploy all files for the references in this project?

Comment: If I click "Publish" from the application properties, will I be able to see which files to include and where they should be installed on the target PC?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the report viewer control to VS 2019 involves installing the NuGet package "Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms". This added a subfolder to the project folder entitled "packages". All .dll files included in that folder need to be installed on the users' PC's.